# Conditional expectation with respect to two sigma algebras

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

> So the problem is to define two sigma algebras, a stochastic variable,
>   specify a probabilty measure on the sample space $\Omega$ and show
>   that the following relation doesn't equal:
>
> $$E[E[X|\mathcal{G}]|\mathcal{F}]\neq E[E[X|\mathcal{F}]|\mathcal{G}]$$
>
> So I started by defining the sigma algebras:
>
> $$\Omega=\{a,b,c\}$$ $$\mathcal{F}=\{\emptyset,\Omega,a,(b,c)\}$$
>   $$\mathcal{G}=\{\emptyset,\Omega,b,(a,c)\}$$ With the stochastic
>   variable $X$: $$X(a)=0,X(b)=1,X(c)=2$$ Probability measures.
>
> P on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$:
>
> $$P(\emptyset)=0,P(\Omega)=1,P(a)=p,P(b\cup c)=1-p$$
>
> P on $(\Omega,\mathcal{G})$:
>
> $$P(\emptyset)=0,P(\Omega)=1,P(b)=p,P(a\cup c)=1-p$$

So far I assume that I haven't messed up.

The expectation part though...I'm stuck.

I tried the following:

$$Y=E[X|\mathcal{G}]$$
$$Z=E[X|\mathcal{F}]$$
$$Y=E[X|\mathcal{G}]=E[X|\mathcal{F}]$$
$$Y=E[X|\mathcal{G}]=E[X|b]1_b+E[X|a\cup c]1_{a\cup c}$$
$$Z=E[X|\mathcal{F}]=E[X|a]1_b+E[X|b\cup c]1_{b\cup c}$$

But after that I can't see how I should progress.

Comment: Well, the basic way is to compute $E(Y\mid\mathcal F)$ and $E(Z\mid\mathcal G)$, of course.

Comment: Well, I haven't done any form of calculation of expected value w.r.t sigma algebras before so I'm some what insecure on what to do exactly.

Comment: But you do propose some such computations yourself, no? Where are the formulas $E[X|\mathcal{G}]=E[X|b]1_b+E[X|a\cup c]1_{a\cup c}$ and $E[X|\mathcal{F}]=E[X|a]1_b+E[X|b\cup c]1_{b\cup c}$ coming from? And why cannot you repeat basically the same computations, to reach $E[E[X|\mathcal{G}]|\mathcal{F}]$ and $E[E[X|\mathcal{F}]|\mathcal{G}]$?

Comment: The formulas come from the definition given in the course litterature. The problem is evaluating after the use of the formula. I assume that $E[X|b]=1*p$, however the expectation w.r.t the union has me a bit insecure. I guess the expecation w.r.t to the union $E[X|a\cup c]=3*(1-p)$?

Comment: Actually $E(X\mid b)=1$ since $X(b)=1$ and $E(X\mid a\cup c)=2P(c)/(P(a)+P(c))$ since $X(a)=0$ and $X(c)=2$. To continue one needs to know $P$, which is left unclear in your post. (Say, you might want to review some *definitions*, no? Thinking of it, to make you do this might be the entire goal of the exercise...)

Comment: Ok! I understand the result of the expectation, it's pretty obvious guess I was thinking of $E[X]$. However on the $P$ I thought you only had to define probabilities for the sets in the sigma algebra used? I guess you have to define for each event?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I will try to solve it now.

> So the problem is to define two sigma algebras, a stochastic variable,
>   specify a probabilty measure on the sample space $\Omega$ and show
>   that the following relation doesn't equal:
>
> $$E[E[X|\mathcal{G}]|\mathcal{F}]\neq E[E[X|\mathcal{F}]|\mathcal{G}]$$
>
> So I started by defining the sigma algebras:
>
> $$\Omega=\{a,b,c\}$$ $$\mathcal{F}=\{\emptyset,\Omega,a,(b,c)\}$$
>   $$\mathcal{G}=\{\emptyset,\Omega,b,(a,c)\}$$ With the stochastic
>   variable $X$: $$X(a)=0,X(b)=1,X(c)=2$$ Probability measures.
>
> P on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$:
>
> $$P(\emptyset)=0,P(\Omega)=1,P(a)=p,P(b\cup c)=P(B)+P(C)=p+p$$
>
> Thus $B$ and $C$ are disjoint
>
> P on $(\Omega,\mathcal{G})$:
>
> $$P(\emptyset)=0,P(\Omega)=1,P(b)=p,P(a\cup c)=P(A)+P(C)=p+p$$
>
> Thus $A$ and $C$ are disjoint

$$Y=E[X|\mathcal{G}]$$
$$Z=E[X|\mathcal{F}]$$
$$E[Z|\mathcal{G}]=E[Y|\mathcal{F}]$$
$$Y=E[X|\mathcal{G}]=E[X|b]1_b+E[X|a\cup c]1_{a\cup c}$$
$$Z=E[X|\mathcal{F}]=E[X|a]1_a+E[X|b\cup c]1_{b\cup c}$$

Solving Y:

$$Y=E[X|\mathcal{G}]=E[X|b]1_b+E[X|a\cup c]1_{a\cup c}$$
$$Y=1*1_b+1*1_{a\cup c} = 1_b+1_{a\cup c}$$

Solving Z:

$$Z=E[X|\mathcal{F}]=E[X|a]1_a+E[X|b\cup c]1_{b\cup c}$$
$$Z=0*1_a+\frac{1*P(b)+2*P(C)}{P(b)+P(c)}$$
$$Z=\frac{3p}{2p}=\frac{3}{2}1_{b \cup c}$$

So far so good I guess?

Thus I end up with:

$$E[1_b+1_{a\cup c}|\mathcal{F}]$$
$$E[\frac{3}{2}1_{b \cup c}|\mathcal{G}]$$

The expected value of a constant, no matter what sigma algebra it's conditioned with ends up being a constant.

$$E[\frac{3}{2}1_{b \cup c}|\mathcal{G}]=\frac{3}{2}E[1_{b \cup c}|\mathcal(G)]$$

And as the events $b$ and $a\cup c$ are disjoint one should be able to seperate them.

$$E[1_b+1_{a\cup c}|\mathcal{F}]=E[1_b|\mathcal{F}]+E[1_{a\cup c}|\mathcal{F}]$$

The expectation of a indicator function is just the probability of the expected value.

The union between $a\cup c$ isn't included in the $\mathcal{F}$ and $b \cup c$ isn't included in $\mathcal{G}$, I guess one says that it isn't $\mathcal{F}$-measurable and $\mathcal{G}$-measurable respectively?. Thus I assume that one ends up with:

$$E[1_b+1_{a\cup c}|\mathcal{F}]=\frac{P(b)}{P(b)+P(C)}+0$$
$$E[1_b+1_{a\cup c}|\mathcal{F}]=\frac{1}{2}$$
$$\frac{3}{2}E[1_{b \cup c}|\mathcal(G)]=0$$

Thus:

$$E[E[X|\mathcal{G}]|\mathcal{F}]=\frac{1}{2}$$
$$E[E[X|\mathcal{F}]|\mathcal{G}]=0$$

So we get:

$$\frac{1}{2}\neq 0$$

Hopefully I haven't messed up.

**EDIT:**

If I remember correctly the union of an event $A$ and $B$ is defined as the event $A$ or $B$ happening or both happening. I also looked up what the indicator function of a union is and got:

$$1_{A\cup B}=1_A+1_B-1_A1_B$$

Substituting the indicatior of the unions I get:

$$ \frac{3}{2}E[1_{b \cup c}|\mathcal{G}]=\frac{3}{2}(E[1_b+1_c-1_b1_c|b]1_b+E[1_b+1_c-1_b1_c|a\cup c]1_{a \cup c})$$

Which then gives:

$$\frac{3}{2}E[1_{b \cup c}|\mathcal{G}]=\frac{3}{2}(1_b+\frac{1}{2}1_{a \cup c})=\frac{3}{2}1_b+\frac{3}{4}1_{a \cup c}$$

The last step is then to evaluate:

$$E[1_b+1_{a \cup c}|\mathcal{F}]=1_a+1_{b \cup c}$$

In the end:

$$1_a+1_{b \cup c} \neq \frac{3}{2}1_b+\frac{3}{4}1_{a \cup c}$$

I assume this holds because if you look at the indicator functions they can't really equate.